# Scatter plot of Multiindex GroupBy()

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to make a scatter plot of a GroupBy() with Multiindex (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-with-multiindex). That is, I want to plot one of the labels on the x-axis, another label on the y-axis, and the mean() as the size of each point.

`df['RMSD'].groupby([df['Sigma'],df['Epsilon']]).mean()` returns:

```
Sigma_ang  Epsilon_K
3.4        30           0.647000
           40           0.602071
           50           0.619786
3.6        30           0.646538
           40           0.591833
           50           0.607769
3.8        30           0.616833
           40           0.590714
           50           0.578364
Name: RMSD, dtype: float64
```

And I'd like to to plot something like: `plt.scatter(x=Sigma, y=Epsilon, s=RMSD)`

What's the best way to do this? I'm having trouble getting the proper Sigma and Epsilon values for each RMSD value.

Comment: You can df['RMSD'].groupby([df['Sigma'],df['Epsilon']]).mean().reset_index() and then plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to Vaishali Garg. Based on his comment, the following works:

`df_mean = df['RMSD'].groupby([df['Sigma'],df['Epsilon']]).mean().reset_index()
plt.scatter(df_mean['Sigma'], df_mean['Epsilon'], s=100.*df_mean['RMSD'])`

Comment: Good to know :)